# Finding the nearest neighbor to a single point in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, latitude-longitude, nearest-neighbor

I'm trying to do a nearest neighbor search that yields a single point as the single "nearest neighbor" to another point in matlab.

I've got the following data:

1. A longitude grid that is size 336x264 "lon"
2. some random point within the bounds of the longitude grid "dxf"

I've tried using MATLAB's "knnsearch" function

https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/knnsearch.html

But sadly when I use the command:

```
idx = knnsearch(lon, dxf)
```

I am met with the error:

```
"Y must be a matrix with 264 columns."
```

Is there an alternative nearest neighbor search I can use to find the nearest neighbor to a single point within MATLAB? Is there a simpler solution I can implement?

I literally just want to find the closest point within the "lon" matrix to point "dxf".

Thanks!
Taylor

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. You have a 336x264 grid and you want to find the grid point that is closest to a point (presumably a 2-coordinate) point `dxf`?

Comment: @beaker That is correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working without Toolboxes, you can construct a simple distance formula yourself:

```
xx = [0:364];  % Not sure what your limits were so just making some up here
yy = [0:264];
[X, Y] = meshgrid(xx,yy);
dxf = [221.7, 109.1];  % Again just pulling numbers from nether regions 

G = [X(:),Y(:)];
d = sqrt( sum( (G-dxf).^2, 2) );
[minDist, idxMinDist] = min(d);
solution = G(idxMinDist,:);
```

You can modify the limits for xx and yy to fit your specific setup accordingly.

Comment: Awesome! I really think this solution will work. The only trouble is my latitude and longitude grids are both 336 x  264 individually. I Need to figure out how to line them up to be a 1-by-2 matrix like those in your file and then I should be golden!

Comment: Sounds like you are pretty close. The lat and lon grids might already be in the 'meshgrid' format. If so, just start at the G=[X(:) Y(:)] step. The X(:) format lists out the 2-d variable X as a 1-d listing.

Comment: Yep! I got the solution, thank you! You're right. All I had to do was specify my lat matrix was equal to lat(:) and then apply your code to it. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You should first convert your grid to an `n-by-2` matrix (if you created this using meshgrid, it's simply `G = [XX(:) YY(:)]`), you can then try it with [`pdist2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) if you have the [Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/index.html) (which you do):

```matlab
[D,I] = pdist2(P, G, 'euclidian', 'Smallest', 1);
```

Where `G` is the grid and `P` is your `m-by-2` array of points to test.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this, and it didn't quite work for me because I didn't make my latitude or longitude grid in meshgrid (they just came from the model output as 336x264 variables.