# Converting grid latitude and longitude data into a 1-by-2 row of lat and lat vs lon data

Tags: matlab, datagrid, latitude-longitude, nearest-neighbor

I've got a question about how I could convert two grids of lat and lon data formatted as such into columns with corresponding data (just a small example of a huge grid):

```
   30.8216   30.8305   30.8395   30.8484   30.8574   30.8663   30.8752   30.8842   30.8931   30.9021   30.9110   30.9200   30.9289   30.9379   30.9468   30.9558   30.9647   30.9737   30.9826   30.9915   31.0005   31.0094
   30.8212   30.8301   30.8391   30.8480   30.8569   30.8659   30.8748   30.8838   30.8927   30.9017   30.9106   30.9196   30.9285   30.9375   30.9464   30.9554   30.9643   30.9733   30.9822   30.9911   31.0001   31.0090
   30.8208   30.8297   30.8387   30.8476   30.8565   30.8655   30.8744   30.8834   30.8923   30.9013   30.9102   30.9192   30.9281   30.9371   30.9460   30.9550   30.9639   30.9728   30.9818   30.9907   30.9997   31.0086
   30.8204   30.8293   30.8383   30.8472   30.8561   30.8651   30.8740   30.8830   30.8919   30.9009   30.9098   30.9188   30.9277   30.9367   30.9456   30.9545   30.9635   30.9725   30.9814   30.9903   30.9993   31.0082
   30.8200   30.8289   30.8379   30.8468   30.8557   30.8647   30.8736   30.8826   30.8915   30.9005   30.9094   30.9184   30.9273   30.9362   30.9452   30.9541   30.9631   30.9721   30.9810   30.9899   30.9989   31.0078
```

and

```
  -92.9589  -92.9584  -92.9579  -92.9575  -92.9570  -92.9565  -92.9561  -92.9556  -92.9552  -92.9547  -92.9542  -92.9538  -92.9533  -92.9529  -92.9524  -92.9519  -92.9514  -92.9510  -92.9505  -92.9500  -92.9496  -92.9491
  -92.9485  -92.9480  -92.9475  -92.9471  -92.9466  -92.9461  -92.9457  -92.9452  -92.9447  -92.9443  -92.9438  -92.9434  -92.9429  -92.9424  -92.9420  -92.9415  -92.9410  -92.9406  -92.9401  -92.9396  -92.9391  -92.9387
  -92.9380  -92.9376  -92.9371  -92.9366  -92.9362  -92.9357  -92.9352  -92.9348  -92.9343  -92.9338  -92.9334  -92.9329  -92.9324  -92.9320  -92.9315  -92.9310  -92.9306  -92.9301  -92.9296  -92.9292  -92.9287  -92.9282
  -92.9276  -92.9272  -92.9267  -92.9262  -92.9258  -92.9253  -92.9248  -92.9243  -92.9239  -92.9234  -92.9229  -92.9225  -92.9220  -92.9215  -92.9211  -92.9206  -92.9201  -92.9197  -92.9192  -92.9187  -92.9183  -92.9178
  -92.9172  -92.9167  -92.9163  -92.9158  -92.9153  -92.9149  -92.9144  -92.9139  -92.9135  -92.9130  -92.9125  -92.9120  -92.9116  -92.9111  -92.9106  -92.9102  -92.9097  -92.9092  -92.9088  -92.9083  -92.9078  -92.9073
```

The points I've listed actually do correspond on the grid FYI.

I'd like to convert them into columns that would display like so with corresponding data lined up.

```
>>[lat, lon]

30.8216    -92.9589
30.8212    -92.9485
30.8208    -92.9380
30.8204    -92.9276
30.8200    -92.9171
```

This is all part of the process for answering a previously mentioned stack question I submitted!
[Finding the nearest neighbor to a single point in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54870941/finding-the-nearest-neighbor-to-a-single-point-in-matlab)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, I'm dumb. Poor indexing understanding.

solution:

```
lat = lat(:)
```

and

```
lon = lon(:)
```